# Different less compilation results between grunt and server side compilation

Tags: magento2, grunt

I got the following theme inheritance setup:
`Vendor/Retail` inherits from `Vendor/Default` which inherits from `Magento/blank`

When compiling the styles with grunt I get no issues. When compiling with server-side compilation some of the blank theme's styles are missing.

I.e. `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_CatalogSearch/web/css/source/_module.less`
or 
`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_layout.less`

Will be included when compiled with grunt but dropped when compiled with server-side compilation.

I'm drawing a bit of a blank here. Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

**Edit:**

I dug into it more and found that it actually only drops the styles that are wrapped in media queries. The common styles are applied. So styles wrapped in:

`.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m)`

will be dropped and not show up in `styles-l.css`. While styles wrapped in:

`& when (@media-common = true) {`

will show up in `styles-m.css`.

This only applies to styles from the blank theme. Styles wrapped in media queries from the child theme are not affected by this issue.

Comment: Are you overriding these two files on your Vendor/Retail theme or Vendor/Default one?

Comment: I think your issue related to this one so check this link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144768/magento-2-css-media-queries-not-working-on

Comment: @EzequielAlba I'm not overriding these at all. That's what makes this even more odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out. In case someone else runs into the same problem I'll post the solution. The server side asset compilation doesn't support double quotes in the `.media-width()` mixin arguments.

I.e.:

`.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = "max") and (@break = @screen__m) {`

will work fine when compiled with Grunt but not at all when using the server side asset compilation.

To make it work on both you need to use:

`.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {`

Answer (score 0):

Check the less "imports" in your custom themes. They all must match the pattern `@import 'foo/_bar.less';`

Pay attention at two things:

1. File path must be wrapped in single quotes ('), not in double quotes (")
2. File path must end with ".less"

Comment: Doesn't look like this is the issue. The `@import` statments are correct. Thanks!